# How to change my IP frequently in a windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-scraping, netsh

I have a security course project. It asks to enter a given website and download its information 20 times(site has 20 subpages), then parse etc. I am using c#'s downloadstring to download and parse the page. However, after the fifth time, website finds out that I am doing those downloads as a robot(programmatically).

What I create as a program is successful until the sixth request.
I download the content and parse the desired information. When I reach the sixth subpage, my pc is blocked.
It is not related with time interval. Because, I used random generated timeouts between 6-12 seconds. However, that does not help. It is definitely related with entry counter of the webpage. It is like " not give permission after 5 request in 30 minutes. If it passes the limit then block it for a (or more) day". Since, I have been blocked for many times. I am using my phone's Hotspot.

I find a solution while I am searching on the internet. People are using IP changing methods via netsh etc. However, I think my IP is static (WiFi) and I could not figure out how to change it programmatically in C# Windows Forms App.
Because of that, I would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried adding delays between requests? What are you using for the user-agent?

Comment: As I said I used timeouts. They were between requests. Site counts the requests based on pc's ip. That's for sure. I need to change my IP.

Comment: Timeout is not the same as delay, a timeout "times out" when a request isn't fulfilled in a period of time. So what happens if you visit this site with Chrome/FF/IE, does it kick you out if you click more than 5 internal links?

Comment: What's the website? Do you include any user-agent in the request headers?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by user agents. If it is related with how I parse the data I just used downloadstring(url) of the c# then I do some string manipulation to reach desired data.

Comment: Google Scholar is the website.

Comment: UserAgent is information regarding your "browser", sent along with the request. It is a header you can set in the request which tells the server how to respond most appropriately just for you. You can Google UserAgents of Firefox, IE, etc. Essentially, it's just a string.

Answer (score 4):

Your ISP most likely gives you a single Dynamic IP Address, which is the IP Address of your computer's access point to the Internet (i.e. the WAN). If so, they control the IP and not you. Even if you have a home network with multiple computers all on different local IP Addresses (LAN), you still aren't changing your WAN IP address which is the address that is effectively blocked.

Also, I am not going to judge, but I would say that if this is for an actual course project, then ethically speaking your instructor most likely would not want you to hammer an innocent website any more than the website's owner wishes for you to hammer it, hence the blocking. My suggestion would be to set your sites on another website that does not have the blocking to complete your coursework. Maybe you can do this against Google.com?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to make a request through a different IP address you could link your application up to several different proxies and switch between them at intervals.

Also, you mention that your IP is static, but there is a difference between your local IP and your external IP address. The IP address given to your WiFi connection is local, but the external IP address which is the one that would be seen by Internet sites is not the same.

If you have a dynamic external IP address one option might be able to programmatically connect to your router and restart it. This is one way to trigger an IP address update if you actually have access to it.

Overall, what you are doing is difficult to achieve for what sounds to be a simple assignment.

Comment: Well, it is a term project. This problem is kinda hard. What you see when you type on google "what is my IP" is what I want to change. My router's IP is static I guess because I live in a dorm right now.

Comment: Changing your external IP will not be feasible then. However, you could use some sort of proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rather involved and eccentric solution that would, however, get around the problem nicely.  Create 4 Amazon EC2 t2.micro instances (Windows) and issue 5 requests each from the EC2 instances.  You can store the result to S3 buckets.  It would take you a lot of work to get this working, but you'd come out the other end also having your first experience of working in the cloud.  And each of those instances would have a different IP.

Also if you spin the same instance up and down a few times, it's unlikely to have the same ip in any case, so you could easily get away with one instance.

In a more serious vein: experiment with changing your user agent string and adding a much more hefty amount of time (minutes, hours) between requests.  Also, turn your hotspot on and off between every five request, which will likely give you a new IP each time.

Comment: LOL. I love it. Overkill, but kind of an "in for a penny, in for a pound" elegance to it.

Comment: Yeah, it's more than a bit silly.  However, the cloud is certainly one way to get out of the limits of a particular machine.

Comment: Added a last paragraph with less arduous things to try.

Comment: As reconnecting to WiFi only *might* get you a new IP, I suggest doing it even more frequently (after each request? you wait anyways, so who cares)

Comment: True, although OP says that he is using phone as hotspot, so I think likelihood of new IP address each time firing up the hotspot is pretty high.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will try and let you know.

Comment: By the way via ipconfig /all, DHCP enabled was yes which makes my connection dynamic I guess.

Comment: Not necessarily. You may be using DHCP to get the IP but the router may be giving you a fixed IP based on your MAC address. However, that makes very little difference as this will be a LAN IP and not your WAN IP.